# Creating child classes that only inherit parents data once

Tags: c#, object, oop, inheritance, parent-child

Currently I'm trying to create some attribute let's call it "DoNotShareWithGrandChildren" that will be used by the highest level parent class but not the children classes below it. The issue I'm running into is I can't find an architecture that allows me to inherit the attributes of the parent class without also adding multiple versions of that attribute.

Attempt 1: "The original issue"

```
class A
{
    bool DoNotShareWithGrandChildren = true;
    
    public A() { DoNotShareWithGrandChildren = true; }
}

class Child :A
{
    bool other = false;
    AnotherChild grandchild;
    
    public Child() : base() 
    {
        grandchild = new AnotherChild(); //Don't create another DoNotShareWithGrandChildren here!
    }
}

class AnotherChild : A
{
    bool somemore = false;
    public AnotherChild() : base() {}
}
```

Attempt 2: "MasterClass" Hold the attribute in a class that calls the parent class

```
class MasterClass
{
A a;
bool DoNotShareWithGrandChildren = true;

    class MasterClass
    {
        A a;
        bool DoNotShareWithGrandChildren = true;
        public MasterClass(A a)
        {
            this.a = a;
        }
    }
    
    class A
    {
        public A() {
        //UNABLE TO ACCESS DoNotShareWithGrandChildren! 
        }
    }
    
    class Child :A
    {
        bool other = false;
        AnotherChild grandchild;
        public Child() : base()
        {
            grandchild = new AnotherChild();
        }
    }
    
    class AnotherChild :A
    {
        bool somemore = false;
        public AnotherChild() : base() { }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters, it seems your example is confusing the term *grandchild* with a *member*. When talking about inheritance, a grandchild would be a derived object with two levels of inheritance.

```cs
public class Grandparent {}
public class Parent : Grandparent {}
public class Child : Parent {}
```

In the above example, `Child` is considered a *grandchild* of the class `Grandparent`.

For your question, though, it's unclear to me what you mean by "inherit the attributes of the parent class without also adding multiple versions of that attribute." Inheritance does not create "multiple versions" of member variables, but it does make them accessible to child classes if the member is given an [access modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) other than `private`.

It sounds like you're asking how to prevent your `grandchild` member of class `Child` from also containing the member variables of class `A`, since `AnotherChild` inherits from class `A`.

This is not possible, since you are inheriting from the class. The member variables of `A` will always be inherited, whether you mark them `private` or otherwise. They will not be accessible if marked `private`, but they will still be there.

A potential solution to your example would be to make the type of the member variable `DoNotShareWithGrandChildren` a custom class that contains the variables you want to use as members, then create this object through **dependency injection**.

```cs
class Data
{
    public bool DoNotShareWithGrandChildren = true;
}

class A
{
    Data attributes;

    public A(Data injected = null)
    {
        if (injected != null)
            attributes = injected;
    }
}

class Child : A
{
    bool other = false;
    AnotherChild grandchild;

    // Inject a Data object into the parent constructor.
    // Your example uses private members, so the only way to assign
    // to "attributes" is through the base constructor.
    public Child() : base(new Data())
    {
        grandchild = new AnotherChild();
    }
}

class AnotherChild : A
{
    bool somemore = false;
    
    public AnotherChild() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Whenever `Child` is created, it will create the `Data` object for the parent class `A`. Inside of `A`, you can then perform operations on the new member `attributes` if it is not null. The member named `grandchild` will have a member named `attributes`, but will no longer have a valid object containing the variable you do not want to be "copied."

The wording of your issue vs. the examples given leads me to believe this situation might just be a misunderstanding of inheritance, though.